# parse, filter and display multi-level json using php

Tags: php, json

Completely new to JSON and am tasked with filtering/sorting a remote JSON using php and embedding formatted results into a CMS.

The data structure looks like this:

```
"Categories":[
  {
     "Name":"Americas",
     "ID":"12345",
     "Countries":[
        {
           "Name":"Argentina",
           "Partners":[
              {
                 "Country":"Argentina",
                 "ID":"4321",
                 "LogoUrl":"logo1.jpg",
                 "Title":"Company A",
                 "AddressBlock":"123 Main Street",
                 "Phone":"444-555-1212",
                 "TollFree":"",
                 "Email":"info@CompanyA.com",
                 "Url":"http://www.CompanyA.com/",
                 "IsVisible":true,
                 "IsDistributor":false
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "Name":"Brazil",
           "Partners":[
              {
                 "Country":"Brazil",
                 "ID":"5432",
                 "LogoUrl":"logo2.jpg",
                 "Title":"Company B",
                 "AddressBlock":"54 Center Street",
                 "Phone":"234-567-3600",
                 "TollFree":"",
                 "Email":"info@CompanyB.com",
                 "Url":"http://www.CompanyB.com",
                 "IsVisible":true,
                 "IsDistributor":false
              },

    "Name":"Canada",
           "Partners":[
              {
                 "Country":"Canada",
                 "ID":"Company C",
                 "LogoUrl":"logo3.Company C",
                 "AddressBlock":"1 Mll Road Floor 27\r\nCanton, ON",
                 "Phone":"555-66-7777",
                 "TollFree":"",
                 "Email":"info@CompanyC.com",
                 "Url":"http://www.CompanyC.com",
                 "IsVisible":true,
                 "IsDistributor":false
              },

           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

]

Ideally I would like to store the key/value pairs in an array and then print them out as a list sorted alphabetically. Each Country could have multiple entries and those set to "IsVisible:false" would need to be hidden.

I did some searching here and I could get to the data source but the array is not 
'exploded' or looped through its dimensions by php and get this returned:

```
Categories:Array
```

using this code:

```
 $string = file_get_contents("https://myURL.securekey");
foreach ($json_a as $key => $value)
 {
   foreach($value as $v)
   {
       echo $v."  ";
   }
 }
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at `json_decode` function. (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: So in you know that you are using JSON, why arent you decoding ist?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Using json_decode gets me the entire dataset, but I am still stumped as to how to loop through and store the values in array variables, then print them out.

Comment: Looks like it's missing the framing curly brackets you can use `json_decode("{".$string."}", true);` to get a multidimensional array that you can easily navigate.

Comment: are you sure you post the correct json string? check your json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hi ROMMEL. yes, I tested it in the link you sent and it came back as "Valid JSON". My reult above is only missing the { and } and the beginning and end becasaue I failed to copy/past the entire into the tope. Either way, it should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: So by using the below:

```
 $string =  file_get_contents('https://secure.json');
 $json = json_decode($string, true);
 foreach($json as $fieldIndex => $fields) { 
    foreach($fields as $valueIndex => $envelope) {
        foreach($envelope as $valueEntry) {
            foreach($valueEntry as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == "Name") {
                echo $value;
                }
                printf("%d - %d - %s: '%s'\n", $key, $value);
                $build[$valueIndex][$key]=$value;               
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($build);
```

I get the following output:

0 - 0 - 0: 'Array' 0 - 0 - 1: 'Array' 0 - 0 - 2: 'Array' 0 - 0 - 3: 'Array' 0 - 0 - 4: 'Array' 0 - 0 - 5: 'Array' array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(9) "Argentina" ["Partners"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["Country"]=> string(9) "Argentina" ["ID"]=> string(36) "4d93" ["LogoUrl"]=> string(52) "http://www.aaa.com/images/partners/aaa.jpg" ["Title"]=> string(14) "Company S.A." ["AddressBlock"]=> string(118) "Main Street - Dock 8 12435- Anytown USA" ["Phone"]=> string(17) "(444) 123-4567" ["TollFree"]=> string(0) "" ["Email"]=> string(28) "info@aaa.com" ["Url"]=> string(35) "http://www.aaaa.com/" ["IsVisible"]=> bool(true) ["IsDistributor"]=> bool(false) } } }

But still unsure as to how to reference the specific name/values to echo them where needed. I assume maybe something like:

```
if ($key == "Title") {
  echo "Title: " . $key . "<br />";
}  esleif ($key == "Country") {
  echo $value;
 }
```

but am stuck on a) where to place it in the loop so it actually grabs the values at the right level and b) the syntax (which must be off because I can still only see anything with a var_dump at the end rather than echo out the values from within the loop.

Comment: Not really an answer, still having trouble getting the variables to set/display. Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Still struggling. I tried calling a start index of "2" which (I think) should first list the "Country" then another foreach loop within that one to list out the names (for a start) of the associated 3rd level entries but not getting any output or errors. I edited the code "answer" code block above for scrutiny:

Comment: I am getting closer..
I think I am getting closer but still no output from this:

$string = file_get_contents('https://secure.json');
$json = json_decode($string, true);
foreach($json as $key => $val) {
$$key = $val; //or $$key = $val;
echo $Name; //echo “Company A”;
}
} I feel like I am having a conversation with myself!:-)